# Modifying data from redux when connecting it to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is it normal to modify data from redux when connecting it to component? like this

redux

```
const itemInitialState = {
    id: null,
    name: ''
};
```

react

```
const Component = connect(
    state => ({
        items: state.items.map(item => {
            item.selected = true;
            return item;
        })
    })
)(_Component);
```

I added one key that was not originally in the state

Comment: Why can't you add it in the initialState?

Comment: @Borjante because this key will be unnecessary there. it's just a simple example that showing that the component gets the modified data from the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's fine to add fields when doing `mapStateToProps` - although the need to do so might be fixed by thinking about the data model more carefully.

What I would fix about your code example is to not mutate the actual redux state, that can cause nasty bugs. So I would fix it to be immutable:

```
const Component = connect(
    state => ({
        items: state.items.map(item => ({
            ...item,
            selected: true
        }))
    })
)(_Component);
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't have any performance implications if that is what you mean. However, I would advise you to move the code to the component. `mapStateToProps` is supposed to perform the sole function of mapping data from the state to the props of a particular component. The modification of the data coming through the props should be left to the component.

Comment: I mean that the component gets the modified data from the state

Answer (score 0):

map function of array always return a new reference. We should not return a new reference from connect function as it will bypass the **shouldComponentUpdate** handling of Connect component returned internally from connect function. It will unnecessary call the render function of this component always whenever any action dispatches that will cause performance implications as your app grows.

**A new reference must always come from reducer.**

So, set any new property it in your component or set it in reducer.